# Mount host directory as cache during docker build (buildkit)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-buildkit, buildkit

Build Kit has given us a range of new options for mounts during build. However I'm struggling to workout the correct way (if it's even possible) to mount a host directory as cache during a build step.

Essentially I have a dockerfile like:

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /app
ADD package.json yarn.lock .
RUN YARN_CACHE_FOLDER=/tmp/yarn yarn --frozen-lockfile
...
```

And I'd like to mount my local `yarn` cache at `/tmp/yarn`

Note: this is in a CI environment

Is there some variation of `buildx` options that supports this?

(I've tried a range of things, but can't seem to land on the right one. I'm currently tempted to find a way to `ADD` the cache since it's actually a multi-stage build and it won't impact the final image, but then I have to get the cache into the build context which is ugly)

Comment: [Should be YARN_CACHE_FOLDER according to the docs](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2181#issuecomment-900325643): [Change the cache path for yarn](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/cache/#toc-change-the-cache-path-for-yarn)  ??

Comment: You're right - I wrote the dockerfile example from memory and got that part wrong. The yarn part is largely irrelevant here though - I want a general solution for providing cache directories from the host (eg: apply to pypi, etc deps as well)